elastic search, searching multiple elements where i can also set a count on the number of data i will recieve for each element
Sorry, if the title is not clear.I want to get results for two brands(lets say brandA & brandB .My query
{ "size":100,
  "query": { 
  "constant_score" : { 
    "filter" : { 
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          { "term": {"brand": "brandA"} },
          { "term": {"brand": "brandB"} }
        ]
      }
      }
    }
  }
}

I want my result in this format:
{{"brand" : "brandA",
          "contentType" : "audiofile",
          "expirationDate" : "2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "pubdate" : "2024-02-26T11:00:00.000Z",
          "editorial" : {
            "keywords" : [ ]
          },
  {"brand" : "brandB",
          "contentType" : "audiofile",
          "expirationDate" : "2100-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "pubdate" : "2024-02-26T11:00:00.000Z",
          "editorial" : {
            "keywords" : [ ]
          }}

Also , is it possible to set limit on the count of data recieved .for e.g , i want if total data recieved 100, then brandA should have 60% data and brandB should have 40% data

Used top_hits in elastic search.
